# NetworkManager Automatic Ethernet Connection

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, netplan

I've recently picked up Rocky Linux 9.1 and am trying to get the basic networking to work correctly using netplan and networkmanager.  There must be something simple missing here...

I have a very simple NetPlan yaml:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
    eno5:
      dhcp4: true
```

Simple - just want an automatic DHCP IP address on eno5 when it is plugged in.  If the network cable is plugged in on boot, or I manually run the following, it works.

```sh
sudo netplan generate
sudo nmcli conn reload
```

However - if I just unplug the ethernet cable and plug it into my second home network, I don't get a new DHCP address on the second network.  The NIC link goes down and back up, but no new connection AND the existing connection doesn't get shut down - it still shows the old IP address, etc... while the cable is unplugged.

How do I get the link coming up to trigger a new connection?  I've found some info on the NetworkManager Dispatcher, but nothing with a simple answer for a basic connection.

Even with a fresh install of Rocky 9.1 with an ethernet connection configured and working during the install - how can it not do something as fundamental as disconnect and reconnect to a network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working - it looks like it was a combination of things.

1. Disable SELinux (or there may be more limited allow options here).
2. Delete the generic NetworkManager port descriptions in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.  New one(s) will be generated in step 3.
3. Add the netplan yaml to describe the desired port config(s) - example above in the question.  Run `sudo netplan generate` to generate the port config(s) in /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.
4. Add /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/99-carrier.conf with the following and restart NetworkManager so it takes effect:

```
[main]
ignore-carrier=no

[device]
match-device=interface-name:en*
carrier-wait-timeout=1000
```

The first section tells NetworkManager to monitor the port carrier for connects/disconnect.  Without this, it wouldn't even disable the connection when the cable was unplugged.  The second section is from a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the link coming up to trigger a new connection?

Wait longer before connecting the cable. NetworkManager has a deliberate delay of 5 seconds after link-down before it starts to deconfigure the interface.

This can be adjusted through `NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
match-device=interface-name:en*
carrier-wait-timeout=1000
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference - though good to know.  Added your timeout change, rebooted, AND counted to 10 - no improvement